# Confgiuring Ubuntu 20.04 with LightDM - How to enable lock screen

Tags: 20.04, lightdm, lock-screen

I want to use lightdm on Ubuntu 20.04.  After installing lightdm and logging in to the desktop environment, I get a message saying

> Screen Lock disabled
>
> Screen Locking requires the GNOME desktop manager

How can I enable screen locking with lightdm?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like there is a security issue related to locking using LightDM

See: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/lightdm/+bug/1806961

One option is to switch to gdm3:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm3
```

Comment: Your link is for Ubuntu 13 and a lot has changed in 7 years. I'm not sure it is relevant.

Comment: Good point, fixed now to launchpad bug.